# table function for all factor variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set:

```
str(df)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3000 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ year      : int  2006 2004 2003 2003 2005 2008 2009 2008 2006 2004 ...
 $ age       : int  18 24 45 43 50 54 44 30 41 52 ...
 $ sex       : Factor w/ 2 levels "1. Male","2. Female": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ maritl    : Factor w/ 5 levels "1. Never Married",..: 1 1 2 2 4 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ race      : Factor w/ 4 levels "1. White","2. Black",..: 1 1 1 3 1 1 4 3 2 1 ...
 $ education : Factor w/ 5 levels "1. < HS Grad",..: 1 4 3 4 2 4 3 3 3 2 ...
 $ region    : Factor w/ 9 levels "1. New England",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ jobclass  : Factor w/ 2 levels "1. Industrial",..: 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ health    : Factor w/ 2 levels "1. <=Good","2. >=Very Good": 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ health_ins: Factor w/ 2 levels "1. Yes","2. No": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ logwage   : num  4.32 4.26 4.88 5.04 4.32 ...
 $ wage      : num  75 70.5 131 154.7 75 ...
```

I want to use `table` function for each factor variable using `data.table`.

**My try:** `df[,lapply(.SD,table),.SDcols = sapply(df,is.factor)]`
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return a named list of tables, with names corresponding to each of the factor variables in your dataset. I've provided some example data below.

Here, `lapply` runs through a data.table that has been subset to only include the variables that are factors and constructs tables of each.

```
lapply(dt[, .SD, .SDcols=names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.factor)]], table)
$origin

A B C E 
2 1 2 1 

$destination

B C D E F 
2 1 1 1 1
```

@mt1022 suggests two alternative syntaxes, the briefer

```
lapply(dt[, .SD, .SDcols = sapply(dt, is.factor)], table)
```

and using the base R syntax (setting `with=FALSE` to directly subset list elements on a logical vector).

```
lapply(dt[, sapply(dt, is.factor), with = F], table)
```

**data**

```
dt <- 
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), origin = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "E"), class = "factor"), 
    destination = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("B", 
    "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), price = c(2L, 2L, 
    3L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("id", "origin", "destination", 
"price"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great:)

Comment: alternatively: `lapply(dt[, .SD, .SDcols = sapply(dt, is.factor)], table)` or `lapply(dt[, sapply(dt, is.factor), with = F], table)`.